# Does order of parameters in logical operators matters equality?

Tags: c#, .net, logical-operators, boolean-logic

I am constructing a class that will contain a logical expression:

```
public enum LogicalOperator { And, Or };

public class LogicalExpression
{
    public LogicalOperator Operator { get; private set; }
    public List<object> Expressions { get; private set; }
}
```

I am thinking about introducing custom `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`. I do not know if an order of expressions in logical expression should imply on equality of such logical expressions.

---

Here is an excerpt of actual logical expressing evaluation:

```
 private bool _evaluateExpression(object expr)
 {
  // ....
        if (expr is LogicalExpression)
        {
            LogicalExpression logExpr = (LogicalExpression)expr;

            switch (logExpr.Operator)
            {
                case LogicalOperator.And:
                    return !logExpr.Expressions.Exists(e => !this._evaluateExpression(e));                        

                case LogicalOperator.Or:
                    return logExpr.Expressions.Exists(e => this._evaluateExpression(e));                        
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: In both types of logical expressions?

Comment: Have you considered creating two properties `Left` and `Right` instead of a list of operands?

Comment: @IlyaIvanov It's already done. But sometimes it's so annoying to make a bunch of internal expressions in logical expressios using just Left and Right pieces;

Comment: it uses similar rules to basic math.  And is equivalent to multiplication.  Or is equivalent to addition, as far as OOp is concerned.  Oh, and Parenthesis are ridiculously important.

Comment: Does your logical system include side effects or exceptions?  For example, in C# you always want to make a distinction between the left and right sides in `x != null && x.Foo != null`; if you evaluated that from right to left then the right side might throw.

Comment: Is your intention to make any two expressions that are logically the same into equal expressions?  You are suggesting here that `x & y` be equal to `y & x`. Should it also be equal to `!(!(x & y))` ?  Should it also be equal to `!(!x | !y)`?  This is called *extensional equality* and it is very difficult to get right.

Comment: you can create one LogicalValue and implement all the operations as DesignPattern:Composite of LogicalValues

Comment: @EricLippert Please see my updated post. To answer your last concern, there is no "not" logical expression. Only "and" and "or" at the moment.